# Кроссбраузерность

Tags: html, css, кроссбраузерность

Решил окунуться в мир ВЕБа и возник вопрос. Я понял что разные браузеры могут по разному отображать инфу и зачастую некоторые браузеры не поддерживают некоторые теги, которые ну очень хотелось бы заиспользовать. Возник следующий  вопрос

Как обойти ограничения? Т.е. как я понимаю, наша цель создать некий универсальный способ, который несмотря на многообразие браузеров заставит отрисовать инфу одинаково, т.е. так как мы задумали, без всякой отсебятины. У меня есть вариант, который как мне видится не совсем верный. В заголовке ХТТП есть поле User-Agent(как то так), в котором указывается агент клиента. И получается что для всего многообразия (как я понял их 4 браузера основных) нам придется создавать html and css.

з.ы. Если я задал очень обширный вопрос, укажите ключевые слова, по которым я могу постичь кроссбраузерную верстку (или что то вроде того). Пока что не знаю куда начать копать

Comment: Вопрос действительно обширный. Но на самом деле есть просто определенные правила которые помогают что либо делать, но для всех. Порой это хаки/обходы (IE must die) иногда вполне легальные решения. Но это не значит что для всех User-Agent нужно создавать свой css и html. Например есть вот такой ресурс как caniuse.com. Там можно подсмотреть поддержку бразуерами разных фич типа html5, cssgrid и т.п.

Comment: На текущий момент есть 4 лидера на которых все делают (Chrome (Blink) ,Firefox,Edge(IE), Safary). Если касательно html то проблем практически нет - для всех браузеров это дело одно и тоже. А вот с css дело обстоит иначе. Там вот и используются css hacks чтобы "сгладить" некоторые проблемы кроссбразуерности.

Comment: Т.е. вы например сначала создаёте стили, а потом смотрите каждое свойство на предмет того, поддерживается ли это свойство всеми браузерами? И если какой то движок не тянет свойство, то вы обхобите эту проблему какими то уловками, как я понял) а есть какой нибудь ресурс например со списком распространенных хаков?

Comment: Ну начнем с того что сначала определяется стэк поддерживаемых браузеров. А потом пилится чтото базовое по  стандартам W3C (то что можно везде) и если вдруг надо что то этакое (что редко) то проверяется в иных браузерах. Обычно pixel-perfect верстка именно так и делается дабы не сломать ничего. По хакам - их очень много - легче просто гуглить по css hack или же пользоваться sass и прочими препроцессорами css. Почти все необычные хотелки можно обыграть стандартными способами (но далеко не все и порой это очень затратно по времени)

Answer (score 1):

> некоторые браузеры не поддерживают некоторые теги, которые ну очень хотелось бы заиспользовать.

С возможностями современного CSS вообще почти безразлично, какие теги использовать. Разве что инпуты разных типов имеют значение, да `<!doctype>, <html>, <head>, <body>` - все остальное можно хоть на одних `<i>` сверстать.